# Get the inserted primary key ids using bulk_save_objects

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy

How can I get the inserted Ids (primary key generated) after using `session.bulk_save_objects`?

I tried this:

```
for x in y:
  obj = Post(...)
  obj_list.append(obj)

session.bulk_save_objects(obj_list)
session.commit()

for i in obj_list:
  print(i.id)
```

The ids are None. The rows are successfully inserted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you need to add `return_defaults = True` in bulk_save_object method like below to get primary key of records

```
for x in y:
   obj = Post(...)
   obj_list.append(obj)
session.bulk_save_objects(obj_list,return_defaults = True)
session.commit()

for i in obj_list:
   print(i.id)
```

Comment: I don't recommend this method because `return_defaults` will cause your statement to insert one at a time, drastically reducing performance and defeating the purpose of the `bulk_save_objects` statement.

Comment: @MathisHard that's a great comment BUT you're missing something important in your reply: how you suggest doing it instead.

Comment: Still a lot cleaner using `bulk_save_objects` than an ugly for-loop.

Answer (score 4):

A more performant way to do this rather than using `bulk_save_objects` which emits an insert statement per value is to use `sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.insert` with a returning clause.

```
insert_stmt = insert(Table).values(dictionary_mappings).returning(Table.id)
ids = db.session.execute(insert_stmt).fetchall()
```

Comment: Thanks. Is the order of ids returned same as order of objects inserted?

Comment: @vestronge probably  you already found it, but on the `returning()` part you can set more fields than the id, so even if are not returned in the same order you can map to the values that you inserted