# Bulk Saving and Updating while returning IDs

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

So I'm using `sqlalchemy` for a project I'm working on. I've got an issue where I will eventually have thousands of records that need to be saved every hour. These records may be inserted or updated. I've been using `bulk_save_objects` for this and it's worked great. However now I have to introduce a history to these records being saved, which means I need the IDs returned so I can link these entries to an entry in a history table. I know about using `return_defaults`, and that works. However, it introduces a problem that my `bulk_save_objects` inserts and updates one entry at a time, instead of in bulk, which removes the purpose. Is there another option, where I can bulk insert and update at the same time, but retain the IDs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the inserted primary key ids using bulk\_save\_objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51131407/get-the-inserted-primary-key-ids-using-bulk-save-objects)

Comment: @CodeLikeBeaker Not really. The majority answer is exactly what I said doesn't work. And the second answer only deals with inserts, not updates at the same time as well.

Comment: Perhaps you could do the UPDATE and the INSERT in two steps as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62388768/2144390) with the INSERT using a RETURNING clause to provide the inserted ID values.

Comment: @GordThompson Yea, I was afraid of that. Right now, how I'm getting the data, I have no idea what's an insert and what's an update, that's why the `bulk_save_objects` was so great, I didn't need to know. Was hoping there would be another option that would allow me to preserve that.

Comment: You don't need to know in advance which rows already exist and which ones are new. You do the `UPDATE` first to update any existing rows, then you do an `INSERT … WHERE NOT IN` or `INSERT … WHERE NOT EXISTS` to insert the new rows.

Comment: @GordThompson Could you provide an answer to this question with code suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired result can be achieved using a technique similar to the one described in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62388768/2144390) by uploading the rows to a temporary table and then performing an UPDATE followed by an INSERT that returns the inserted ID values. For SQL Server, that would be an OUTPUT clause on the INSERT statement:

```py
main_table = "team"

# <set up test environment>
with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(sa.text(f"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [{main_table}]"))
    conn.execute(
        sa.text(
            f"""
            CREATE TABLE [dbo].[{main_table}](
                [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
                [prov] [varchar](2) NOT NULL,
                [city] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
                [name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
                [comments] [varchar](max) NULL,
             CONSTRAINT [PK_team] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
            (
                [id] ASC
            )
            )
            """
        )
    )
    conn.execute(
        sa.text(
            f"""
            CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UX_team_prov_city] ON [dbo].[{main_table}]
            (
                [prov] ASC,
                [city] ASC
            )            
            """
        )
    )
    conn.execute(
        sa.text(
            f"""
            INSERT INTO [{main_table}] ([prov], [city], [name])
            VALUES ('AB', 'Calgary', 'Flames')            
            """
        )
    )

# <data for upsert>
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ("AB", "Calgary", "Flames", "hard-working, handsome lads"),
        ("AB", "Edmonton", "Oilers", "ruffians and scalawags"),
    ],
    columns=["prov", "city", "name", "comments"],
)

# <perform upsert, returning IDs>
temp_table = "#so65525098"
with engine.begin() as conn:
    df.to_sql(temp_table, conn, index=False, if_exists="replace")
    conn.execute(
        sa.text(
            f"""
            UPDATE main SET main.name = temp.name, 
                main.comments = temp.comments
            FROM [{main_table}] main INNER JOIN [{temp_table}] temp
                ON main.prov = temp.prov AND main.city = temp.city
            """
        )
    )
    inserted = conn.execute(
        sa.text(
            f"""
            INSERT INTO [{main_table}] (prov, city, name, comments)
            OUTPUT INSERTED.prov, INSERTED.city, INSERTED.id
            SELECT prov, city, name, comments FROM [{temp_table}] temp
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT * FROM [{main_table}] main
                WHERE main.prov = temp.prov AND main.city = temp.city
            )
            """
        )
    ).fetchall()
    print(inserted)
    """console output:
    [('AB', 'Edmonton', 2)]
    """

# <check results>
with engine.begin() as conn:
    pprint(conn.execute(sa.text(f"SELECT * FROM {main_table}")).fetchall())
    """console output:
    [(1, 'AB', 'Calgary', 'Flames', 'hard-working, handsome lads'),
     (2, 'AB', 'Edmonton', 'Oilers', 'ruffians and scalawags')]
    """
```